# How to combine 2 columns into a new one in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table with 3 columns and I have to put the values from 2 columns into one in descending order.

```
+---+---+---+
| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+    
| z | 1 | 2 |  
| f | 5 | 7 | 
| s | 9 | 5 |
+---+---+---+
```

Using this example the output would be putting the values from column B and C into one like this:

```
+---+----+
| A | B  |
+---+----+ 
| s | 9  |
| f | 7  |
| f | 5  |
| s | 5  | 
| z | 2  |
| z | 1  |
+---+----+
```

My current code:

```
 String SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT a, b, c AS b FROM _table ORDER BY b DESC" ;
```

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First combine the two queries using `UNION` and then do the descending order to the combined result.

**Query**

```
 SELECT * FROM
 (
     SELECT A,B
     FROM tbl
     UNION
     SELECT A,C
     FROM tbl
 )t
 ORDER BY t.B DESC;
```

In your case,

```
String SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT A,B FROM _table UNION SELECT A,C FROM _table)t ORDER BY t.B DESC" ;
```

### [Fiddle demo for your reference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b4f58/1)

**Screenshot**

[image]

Hope this will help you out.