# How to combine two columns into one in Sqlite and also get the underlying value of the Foreign Key?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I want to be able to combine two columns from a table into one column then to to be able to get the actual value of the foreign keys. I can do these things individually but not together.

Following the answer below I was able to combine the two columns into one using the first sql statement below.

[How to combine 2 columns into a new one in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626231/how-to-combine-2-columns-into-a-new-one-in-sqlite)

The combining process is shown below:

```
+---+---+
|HT | AT| 
+---+---+    
|1  | 2 |  
|5  | 7 | 
|9  | 5 |
+---+---+
```

into one column as shown:

```
+---+
|HT |
+---+   
| 1 |  
| 5 | 
| 9 |
| 2 |
| 7 |
| 5 |
+---+
```

The second SQL statement show's the actual value of each foreign key corresponding to each foreign key id. The Foreign Key Table.

```
+-----+------------------------+
|T_id |         TN             | 
+-----+------------------------+    
| 1   | 'Dallas Cowboys        |  
| 2   | 'Chicago Bears'        | 
| 5   | 'New England Patriots' |
| 7   | 'New York Giants'      |
| 9   | 'New York Jets'        |
+-----+------------------------+
```

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT M.HT FROM M UNION SELECT M.AT FROM Match)t"
```

The second sql statement lets me get the foreign key values for each value in M.HT.

```
sql = "SELECT M.HT, T.TN FROM M INNER JOIN T ON M.HT = T.Tid WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', M.ST) BETWEEN \'2015-08-01\' AND \'2016-06-30\' AND M.Comp = 6 ORDER BY M.ST"
```

Result of second SQL statement:

```
+-----+------------------------+
| HT  |         TN             | 
+-----+------------------------+    
| 1   | 'Dallas Cowboys        |  
| 5   | 'New England Patriots' |
| 9   | 'New York Jets'        |
+-----+------------------------+
```

But try as I might I have not been able to combine these queries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following will work (assuming that the tables are Match and T and baring the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses for brevity/ease) :-

```
SELECT DISTINCT(m.ht), t.tn
FROM 
    (SELECT Match.HT FROM Match UNION SELECT Match.AT FROM Match) AS m
    JOIN T ON t.tid = m.ht 
    JOIN Match ON (m.ht = Match.ht OR m.ht = Match.at)
/* WHERE and ORDER BY clauses using Match as m only has columns ht and at */
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', Match.ST) 
    BETWEEN \'2015-08-01\' AND \'2016-06-30\' AND Match.Comp = 6 
ORDER BY Match.ST
;
```

- Note only tested without the WHERE and ORDER BY clause.

That is using :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Match;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Match (ht INTEGER, at INTEGER, st TEXT DEFAULT (datetime('now')));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t (tid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, tn TEXT);
INSERT INTO T (tn) VALUES('Cows'),('Bears'),('a'),('b'),('Pats'),('c'),('Giants'),('d'),('Jets');
INSERT INTO Match (ht,at) VALUES (1,2),(5,7),(9,5);
/* Directly without the Common Table Expression */
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(m.ht), t.tn, 
    Match.st /*<<<<< Added to show results of obtaining other values from Matches >>>>> */
FROM 
    (SELECT Match.HT FROM Match UNION SELECT Match.AT FROM Match) AS m
    JOIN T ON t.tid = m.ht 
    JOIN Match ON (m.ht = Match.ht OR m.ht = Match.at)
/* WHERE and ORDER BY clauses here using Match */
;
```

- Noting that limited data (just the one extra column) was used for brevity

Results in :-

[image]